Propositional calculus - variable assignment proof
I am having trouble to formally prove the following:
let α,β,γ be well formed formulas.
prove that if Var(α) ∩ (Var(β) ∪ Var(γ)) = ∅ and β(α/p1)=γ(α/p1) then β=γ
It would be great to get some direction of proof.

What have you tried? What techniques do you know of for proving things about formulas?

I tried to prove it by induction on the structure of  or assuming by contradiction. But it all leads to a dead end.Just to give the context, in the previous section I had to give example of a case where (/1)=(/1) and  is not equal to , so I gave:  = p2, =(p1 and p2), =(p2 and p1)

What's the dead end? Please edit the question with all relevant information about what you've already tried.

Yes, by induction. If p1 is not occurring, then ok. Ifbeta is only p1, then ok. If beta is not-delta, assume that the prperty holds fod delta (induction hypothesis), ant it is ok.
